# How to prove this closure is compact?

Tags: compactness, equicontinuity

> Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space, and $\mathscr{F}$ an equicontinuous family
> of functions from $X$ to itself. Suppose that $g: X → R$ is continuous.

> Show that the family $\mathscr{G} = \{g ◦ f: f \in \mathscr{F} \subset C(X, R)\}$
> is equicontinuous and that $\overline{\mathscr{G}}$ is compact.

I have finished the proof of the equicontinuous and because $X$ is compact, it is actually uniformly equicontinuous. But I'm stuck in the proof of $\overline{\mathscr{G}}$ is compact. I try to apply the Arzela-Ascoli theorem and prove that $\overline{\mathscr{G}}$ is uniformly bounded and uniformly equicontinuous and so it is compact. But I'm stuck. I also try that assume $\overline{\mathscr{G}}$ is not compact and apply the Arzela-Ascoli theorem show that $\mathscr{G}$ is not uniformly equicontinuous so get the contradiction. But I'm also stuck because I don't know how to prove $\overline{\mathscr{G}}$ is bounded.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: $g(X)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. What relation has this fact to the boundedness of $\overline{\mathscr{G}}$?

Comment: I know that every element in $\overline{\mathscr{G}}$ is bounded, but how to show that $\overline{\mathscr{G}}$ is uniformly bounded? $\overline{\mathscr{G}}$ could be infinite.

Comment: Let's start with $\mathscr{G}$. Can you find a uniform bound for that?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find the clue here. If $\mathscr{G}$ is infinite, how to guarantee that it is bounded?

Comment: What do you know about the values of a member of $\mathscr{G}$?

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Could you please give me some hints on how to show that $\mathscr{G}$ is bounded? I'm really stuck here.

Comment: @jiayin Please stop vandalizing your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $f \in \mathscr{F}$ we have
$$(g \circ f)(X) = g(f(X)) \subseteq g(X)\,.$$
Now $X$ is compact and $g$ continuous, hence $g(X)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, thus there is a $c > 0$ such that $g(X) \subseteq [-c,c]$. This implies
$$\lvert g(f(x))\rvert \leqslant c$$
for all $f \in \mathscr{F}$ and $x \in X$. This global weak inequality is preserved under pointwise limits (a fortiori under uniform limits), hence
$$\lvert h(x)\rvert \leqslant c$$
holds for all $h \in \overline{\mathscr{G}}$ and all $x \in X$.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is quite straightforward. I omitted that $g(X)$ is bounded. Thanks again!